# No change after solr+openNLP integration

Tags: solr, lucene, opennlp

I'm following this wiki http://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP to integrate solr+openNLP.

I'm trying to apply named recognition(person name) token but im not seeing any change. my schema.xml looks like this:

```
<field name="text" type="text_opennlp_pos_ner" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_opennlp_pos_ner" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory"
      tokenizerModel="opennlp/en-token.bin"
    />
    <filter class="solr.OpenNLPFilterFactory"
      nerTaggerModels="opennlp/en-ner-person.bin"
    />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

I want to see only person names in the field "text" but I'm not.. Please guide..?

Comment: could you describe what are you doing? i mean how you recognize that you don't have changes?

Comment: @ Mysterion:description:I'm trying to get only names of person in the "text" field. "Text" field contains a copy of "content" field which is indexed with a website. I'm recognising it through this command "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=text:*" Instead of seeing only person names, I'm seeing the entire website contents? where i'm goin wrong? could you please tel me?

Comment: @  Mysterion: Can you please reply..?

Comment: I actually have no idea

Comment: did this get solved?

Answer (score 0):

Use `solr.FilterPayloadsFilterFactory` or `solr.StripPayloadsFilterFactory`.

Usage example [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP#solr.FilterPayloadsFilterFactory)